# Memory issues using an inner BroadcastReceiver within an activity

Tags: java, android, performance

I have been around for some month now coding Android Application as a hobby. I have now come to a point where I had to realize that the real world is not as easy as some tutorials may sound like and that an app performs really different on several devices. Currently, I am worried about memory and CPU usage in my applications. I never really spend any time to optimize or to even think about my applications in terms of memory usage and well, here I go, realizing that I probably really messed up in many points and there is a lot to clean up.

Unfortunately, I am having a hard time looking for tutorials and explanations that are up to date and are understandable for newbies. Many tutorials are dealing with the old android studio versions and very good tutorials are about working with DDMS. I feel like the new Android Profiler (in Android Studio 3.0) is missing some important insights. 
It would be great if you could assist me in washing away some misunderstandings I currently have irritated by a long night reading to much how-to and tutorials.

I am currently wondering about BroadcastReceiver within an activity which is an often used practice.
So, for example, I have a music application. The `MainActivity` is starting a `Service` to handle the playback of music. This `Service` reports back to the activity about the current state of the playback and the passed played time. 
The reporting is solved by sending an intent from the `Service` to an inner `BroadcastReceiver` within the named  `MainActivity`. 
Here is a simplified example to let you grasp what I mean:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private class MusicPlayerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //update UI elements
            seekBar.post(() -> seekBar.setProgress(POSITION)); //using post for thread safeness? 

            //lots of other UI calls 

        }

    }
}
```

As I was not sure if the following problems are raised through other wrong implementation I decided to post the full code of the intent receiving:

```js
                            int currentPos = intent.getIntExtra(KEY_POSITION, -1);

                            //check if large player is showing, if not it should display mini Player
                            if(playerRootView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                                mini_Player.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            //if the loading hasn't been triggered away yet, this one will help
                            if(relativeLayoutLoading.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                relativeLayoutLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                playerControls.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            TrackModel mCurrentTrack=MusicDataMng.getInstance().getCurrentTrackModel();
                            if (currentPos > 0 && mCurrentTrack != null) {
                                long duration = currentPos / 1000;
                                String minute = String.valueOf((int) (duration / 60));
                                String seconds = String.valueOf((int) (duration % 60));
                                if (minute.length() < 2) {
                                    minute = "0" + minute;
                                }
                                if (seconds.length() < 2) {
                                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                                }
                                String timePassed = minute + ":" + seconds;

                                if(!seeking) {
                                    // will update the "progress" propriety of seekbar until it reaches progress
                                    seekBar.post(() -> {
                                        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seekBar, "progress", currentPos);
                                        animation.setDuration(1000); // 0.5 second
                                        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                                        animation.start();
                                    });

                                } else {
                                    seekBar.post(() -> seekBar.setProgress(currentPos));
                                }
                                mini_ProgressBar.post(() -> mini_ProgressBar.setProgress(currentPos));
                                trackDurationStart.post(() -> trackDurationStart.setText(timePassed));

                            }
```

What I can see now in the Android Profiler when recording memory after I started to play a song is this: 
[image: Screenshot of Android Profiler excerpt]

My questions regarding this are the following:

1. I feel like there should not be for each intent updating the position an instance of the BroadcastReceiver. Why are they still stored and not removed after GC?
2. The instances are holding a reference to the MainActivity in `arg$1.this$0`

   - from the reference id, I can see that they are pointing to the same `MainActivity`. Does that mean that they just store a pointer to that reference or is every instance of the BroadcastReceiver storing a full reference to the MainActivity? If so it would mean heavy memory usage, right?
3. Would this misbehaviour disappear when I make the `BroadcastReceiver` static and then adding a constructor that will set WeakReferences like it is described [here](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8)?

If you feel I really missed something about this hole performance topic or should read this or that tutorial or book I would be really thankful for any recommendation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `I feel like there should not be for each intent updating the position an instance of the BroadcastReceiver.` ?? There is only one. Only one in your activity. And it listens.

Comment: @greenapps alright, thank you for pointing the obvious out. This was my misunderstanding about how to interpret these data :)

Comment: But then what is your concern about memory and cpu usage? I never bother. I always do as if my app(s) have the whole kingdom :-).

Comment: @greenapps in this Case there isn’t any problem with the activity reference that is true. But what is about that every lambda call from the broadcast receiver keeps being stored? This is due to the fact that it is a inner nested class calling, right?

Comment: Sorry.. Have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring your broadcast receiver as a nested class it holds a reference to the enclosing class (MainActivity). You could call it a "pointer" as you described to the MainActivity instance (there is only one instance in the memory).

I didnt go through the blog you linked but making it static will remove this instance "pointer/reference".

My advice would be to go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html to get a better understanding of the nested classes in Java and when/how to best use them.

As for your specific problem i would recommend using an EventBus and sending your player updates on the Bus where any interested classes can subscribe and listen to them.

http://square.github.io/otto

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Thank you! Really interesting idea with the event bus taking action for that, definitely going to try this out.